# Laravel y Jquery : Ayuda con error NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Estoy utilizando este plugin de jquery , [jQuery Plugin For Editable Table Rows - Table Edits](http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-For-Editable-Table-Rows-Table-Edits.html) , para hacer tablas editables en una aplicación hecha en Laravel pero tengo el siguiente problema:  Cuando quiero enviar los datos del registro que quiero editar mediante ajax me arroja el error *NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:* Entiendo que esto tiene que ver con la definición de las rutas, pero  en el archivo route.php si están definidas e incluso también probé definir una ruta especifica para acceder al metodo *update* directamente pero tampoco funcionó. 
Espero que me puedan ayudar. Saludos y gracias de antemano.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Laravel</title>

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('components/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css') }}">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::asset('components/datatables.net-bs/css/editor.bootstrap.css')}}">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::asset('components/datatables.net-bs/css/editor.dataTables.css')}}">

    </head>
    <body>
          <h1>Ejemplo de Edici&oacute;n en el lugar con jQuery</h1>

<div class="container">
              <div class="mensaje"></div>
  <table class="table tablaEdit" id="tablaEditable">
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellidos</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Telefono</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody>
       @foreach($tablas as $tabla) 
      <tr data-id="{{$tabla->id}}">

        <td id="nombre" class="tvalor" data-field="nombre"> {{ $tabla->nombre}}</td>
        <td id="apellidos" data-field="apellidos"> {{ $tabla->apellidos }}</td>
        <td id="email" data-field="email"> {{ $tabla->email }}</td>
        <td id="telefono" data-field="telefono"> {{ $tabla->telefono }}</td>

      </tr>

      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js') }}"> </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/script.js') }}"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/table-edits.js') }}"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.12/datatables.min.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#tablaEditable tr").editable({

  keyboard: true,
  dblclick: true,
  button: true,
  buttonSelector: ".edit",
  dropdowns: {},
  maintainWidth: true,


  save: function(values) {
  var idusuario = $(this).data('idusuario'); //captura el id en la tabla

     $.ajax({
            url: '/editar/' + idusuario,
            data: values,  
            type: "PUT",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                  alert("Editado");
            }

        });

  }

});


    });
```

Rutas

```
 Route::put('/editar/{idusuario}', 'TablaController@update');

Route::resource('/', 'TablaController' , ['except' => ['update']]);
```

listado de rutas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error en consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

UPDATE: Solucionado , tenia un par de errores en la definicion del modelo y ademas quité la funcion JSON.stringfy de jQuery ya que no era muy util.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La definición correcta de la ruta debería incluir el parámetro del modelo (id normalmente):

```
Route::post('/editar/{id}', 'TablaController@update');
```

De hecho podrías utilizar [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-model-binding) para que Laravel cargue el modelo automáticamente con la ruta.

Pero para poder usar esa ruta independiente tendrías que NO generar la ruta cuando usas el método `resource()`, de lo contrario vas a tener rutas redundantes y esto puede traer problemas:

```
Route::resource('/', 'TablaController', ['except' => ['update']]);
```

---

En caso que utilices solo `Route::resource()`, debes tener en cuenta que el verbo que utiliza el método `update()` es PUT y no POST (puedes verlo en el listado de rutas que publicaste).

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder. Hice lo que me sugeriste y ya al menos no me arroja el error al principio. Pero ahora me surgio este error: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: " que viene del controlador. Si aun logro resolverlo editare el post. Gracias por la ayuda !!

Comment: Editado con la solución utilzada

Comment: Puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te fue útil para ayudar a resolver tu problema.